# router.guardRoute is not being called

Tags: durandal, sammy.js, hottowel

This is probably a simple one..

I am trying to override the routers guardRoute function and it seems that my version is not being called.

**Code**

```
app.start().then(function () {
    router.useConvention();
    viewLocator.useConvention();
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');

    router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
        logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
    };

    router.guardRoute = function (routeInfo, params, instance) {
        logger.logError('guardRoute called', routeInfo, 'main', true);
        return false;
    };
});
```

**Edit 1 - Entire main.js file shown**

```
require.config({
    paths: { "text": "durandal/amd/text" }
});

define(function (require) {
   var system = require('durandal/system'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),
        router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
        viewLocator = require('durandal/viewLocator'),
        logger = require('services/logger');

    system.debug(true);

    app.title = "my app";

    app.start().then(function () {
        router.useConvention();
        viewLocator.useConvention();
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');

        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
            logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
        };

        router.guardRoute = function (routeInfo, params, instance) {
            logger.logError('guardRoute called', routeInfo, 'main', true);
            //return false;
        };
    });

});
```

I do not get my log message and the router continues to process the request.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I presume this is your main.js, but this is NOT the whole code. logger should be defined somewhere! This could cause (a part of) the problem?

Comment: I'll update the question to show my entire main.js file.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked my own project and the files but I totally can't find the function in Router.js (provided by DurandalJS). Which version do you have, maybe the guardRoute is added in a later version?

YES that is definitly it, if I go to https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/App/durandal/plugins/router.js I see the function but this does NOT come in line with my own code! (so I do have a older version and you probably do to!)

Beaware when you implement this new code somethings might not work properly, let me know if it worked or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked the release form of Durandal 1.2.0 https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/Changes.txt
And yes the guardRoute is added from this version.

You can check which versions you have in the packages.config file!

The hottowel template you own is probably version 1.1.1 of DurandalJS, this I can see in the NuGet Package Manager. If I want to download the HotTowel template right now it contains DurandalJS 1.1.1

You should update Durandal in the NuGet Manager and also the Durandal Router, then everything should work fine!

I have done this update to (but not from hottowel) and I clicked update ALL, DON'T click this, this will also update/ download Durandal Starterskit and your back at '0'.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly now...  This was exactly the problem.  Thanks!