# Durandal - how to "protect" a route?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

In my `shell.js`, I have some options in the UI that a user can select before navigating to the `child.js` vm.  The `child.js` vm requires this option data to be provided.

If I navigate to `#/child` directly, currently I get some errors because this data has not been provided.  This is the expected behavior... though I'd like to somehow protect the child.js view from being accessed directly.

The ideal scenario is that if a user refreshes the page on the child view or navigates directly to it (could be captured by checking to see if the required option data exists), I push them to another view via a different route.  I should only be able to access the child vm if the required option data is there.

I tried doing this:

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate
};

function activate() {
   alert("ACTIVATED");
    if (<check for data exists>) {
        vm.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(<data>, mapping);
    } else {
        toastr.error("session data lost");
        router.navigateTo("#/getdata");
    }
};

return vm;
```

however I can see the entire page load and code above `activate` run before the new view is loaded from router.navigateTo when the data is not there.

**How can I either totally exit the vm at either router.navigateTo above (and prevent any further execution), or somehow protect the route from even loading the vm if certain data is unavailable (preferred)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `router.guardRoute` as described at http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/.
Make sure that you're running Durandal 1.2 [router.guardRoute is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577523/router-guardroute-is-not-being-called)

#### Updated router link  for Durandal 2.0. based on comment:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/

Comment: Thanks again for the help Rainer (you're saving me today).  I did see this in the docs but couldn't find an example of its usage (other then logging, from the second link).  Would you mind posting an example of conditional routing?

Comment: Sorry, I've no example available, but it should be pretty straight forward to implement. If you run into issues feel free to come up with a fiddle based on https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2 and I'll take a look.

Comment: Your durandaljs link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, you could use canActivate hook method. This method is called before calling activate. You could stop the transition returning false from this method.

```
  vm = {
     canDeactivate : function(data) {
       if (! data.foo) return false;
     }
  }
```